# React Native Flex Layout With Absolute Size

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have the following flex layout defined for use with a React Native app (please excuse the ugly background color):

```
const master = StyleSheet.create({
    component: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#ff69b4",
    },
    topSection: {
        //flex: 1,
    },
    bottomSection: {
        //flex: 2,
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        height: 50,
    }
});
```

I need the bottom section to be an absolute height (say, 50px), and the top section to fill all other space so that I can put some menu icons there.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What if you decomment top section: `flex: 1`?

Comment: [Here a snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/sadistic-ice-cream)

Comment: And a tasty snack it was, too. Milore, if you'd like to post your response as an answer, I'll accept it and give you some imaginary points.

Comment: I had already wrote an answer, but then I realised that it was just changing that line and so I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fit your request?

```
  component: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ff69b4'
  },
  bottomSection: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 50,
  },
  topSection: {
    flex: 1
  }
```

Supposing `component` is the container, like

```
  <View style={styles.component}>
    <View style={styles.topSection} />
    <View style={styles.bottomSection} />
  </View>
```

or take a look at this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/sadistic-ice-cream)

Comment: Looks good. The original answer disappeared on me as I was looking at it.